# $.ajax() POST command not connecting to WCF service

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf, rest

I am able to connect to the service using a simple form POST, but $.ajax method does not work and I get an error: "No transport"

The interface/contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    Msg updateMessageJSON(Msg message);
}
```

The datacontract and data members:

```
[DataContract]
public class Msg{
    [DataMember]
    public string GUID;

    [DataMember]
    public string message;
}
```

The service class:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
 [WebInvoke(
    Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "updateMessageJSON"
    )]
    public Msg updateMessageJSON(Msg message)
    {
        using (masterEntities1 entx = new masterEntities1())
        {
            entx.AddToErrorMessageDatas(
                    new ErrorMessageData() { messageData = message.message }
                );
            entx.SaveChanges();
        }

        message.GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        return message;
    }
```

Configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="JSONServiceTest.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/JSONServiceTest/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="JSONServiceTest.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="JSONServiceTest.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

jQuery:

```
function exec() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/JSONServiceTest/Service1/json/updateMessageJSON",
            type: 'POST',
            data: "{ 'message':'get the new guid','GUID':''}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            },

            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Use `console.log(thrownError)` instead.

Comment: @Jack: the error returned is "No transport"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because you're doing cross-site scripting, assuming that `http://localhost:8733` is not also the address of your page (ports make a difference).

Use JSONP instead. Your response should be something like:

```
myCallback(['your data structure here'])
```

Where `myCallback()` is a valid function in your JavaScript. The `$.ajax` call needs this as well:

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
```

See also: [Remote JSON](http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/)

Comment: Thanks Jack, but after getting the transport error, I changed the webhttp binding configuration with the following:  <binding name="crssdmn" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/> That works with JSON. Is that a security issue? Is it necessary to use JSONP? Won't we still have to enable access to cross domain scripting?